# Namespace Trouble in XML Documents for SOAP Requests

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, namespaces

I am consuming a soap webservice as a client. For generating the SOAP-Requests documents i am using XSLT.

Lets imagine i want to call the SOAP-Action "getNumber", i'll render the following document:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:abc="xyz">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
    <abc:getNumber>
        <abc:param1>123</abc:param1>
    </abc:getNumber>
</soapenv:Body>
```

As you can see, the namespace is correctly defined in the Envelope-Tag. When i sent this xml to the webservice, the parser on the other side gives an error because the namespace is (for me obviously not) missing.

If i ask the support of the webservice they say, i have to put the namespace on the method like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header />
    <soapenv:Body>
        <abc:getNumber xmlns:abc="xyz">
            <abc:param1>123</abc:param1>
        </abc:getNumber>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I dont understand why and they cant give me a reasonable explanation.

For me its a good style to define the namespaces on a central place, like in the "xsl:stylesheet"-Tag, so i have to define it once and use it everywhere in the stylesheet.

If i make it like they want, i have to write it to at least 7 or 8 places in the stylesheet, because i am using several templates to render the single parts of the document and on every template i have to write all the namespace declarations again.

My guess is, that their (one of a very well known) framework is not good enough to extract a XML Fragment properly from the whole XML-Document.
It will only cut out the node "abc:getNumber" and threat it as a new XML-Document and will suddenly notice, that there is no namespace defined.

First Question: Am I right with my assumption? Are the (well known) Frameworks for SOAP-Processing to bad to get this?

Second Question: Does anybody know a trick to influence the appearance of XML-Namespaces in XSL without writing them again and again to the single templates i use?

Comment: **1**. Yes (your XML is well-formed; I don't know anything about any frameworks). **2**. No.

Comment: The first question was about if my assumption with "faulty frameworks" was right, not if my xml is well formed ... the xml is well formed, i know. I am searching for a solution to handle this bad behavior of the framework without writing duplicate and difficult maintainable code ...

Comment: Well, if the XML is well-formed and the consuming application cannot parse it, then the application being faulty is a fact, not an assumption. WRT to #2, I don't know of a general way to tell an XSLT processor where to place the namespace declarations. In fact, you may find it's not easy to control it with specific code, either (you didn't post any XSLT code, so I cannot be more specific here).